# How to redirect to newly created document page after submitting the form firestore for web

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to redirect to the newly created document page after successfully creating the document. Below is my code for that

```
db.collection("problems").add({
                statement: statement,
                details: {
                    difficulty: difficulty,
                    type: type,
                    title: title
                },
                tags: tags,
                timestamp: {
                    created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
                    modified: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
                }
            })
            .then(function(docRef) {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                var problemID;
                docRef.get()
                .then( (doc) => {
                    if(doc.exists) {
                        console.log(doc.data());
                        console.log(doc.id);
                        problemID = doc.id;
                        window.location.replace("/practice/problemID");
                    }
                })

            })
```

But this does not work. Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: the above code is from UI or server (nodejs) ?

Comment: this code is from UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the ID.

window.location.replace("/practice/"+problemID);

```
db.collection("problems").add({
                statement: statement,
                details: {
                    difficulty: difficulty,
                    type: type,
                    title: title
                },
                tags: tags,
                timestamp: {
                    created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
                    modified: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
                }
            })
            .then(function(docRef) {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                var problemID;
                docRef.get()
                .then( (doc) => {
                    if(doc.exists) {
                        console.log(doc.data());
                        console.log(doc.id);
                        problemID = doc.id;
                        window.location.replace("/practice/"+problemID);
                    }
                })

            })
```